# Android: best way to handle callback result to avoid crash?

Tags: android, callback, crash, asynchronous

I'm working with app that need to call webservice to get data. I'm using Retrofit with callback to handle result data. It mean that i call webservice asynchronously.

And there is a problem that, some time, user move to other activity while the request is not complete. So, when it complete it call some resource that doesn't exist anymore -> lead to crash.

Except for catching NPE at here, could you give some other idea for that?

Comment: use volley request.it has request cancellation.as preferred google,good to use.

Comment: thanks for your help, RamBabu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [this article](http://www.mdswanson.com/blog/2014/04/07/durable-android-rest-clients.html) that explain a great structure for Android app based on bus events.

In onResume/onPause, you **attach** the current fragment/activity to the events, and you **subscribe** to event in the fragment.

In the application, you can register for example a **UserService** that will handle an bus event like `postLogin` and once done, create and send a new event call `onLogged` (for example).

I'm using it in a new app, and it very convenient and clean. You can avoid nasty stuff and have the same result of network request in many places for example to update the NavigationView at the same time as the current Login fragment.

Comment: great, i'm using bus event now but dont think about it. Thank you, i'm still on it.